# class member initialization in c++11 done properly

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization

I am trying to update some older code for Objects (A) with big initialization lists by initializing the member variable for Object (B) in the header.

```
class A
{
  public:
  A(); //a lot of members initialized in constructor
  A(const A &cpy);  //has a defined cctor too

  B* member1 = new B("needs a string"); //works fine
  B member2 = B("needs a string"); //error: ‘B::B(const B&)’ is private
  B member3("needs a string"); //error: expected identifier before string

  B member4{(const char*)"needs a string"};  //What I was looking for
}
```

But I need non pointer members too but can't find a way to initialize them. For various reasons I can not use the copy constructor of B.

Comment: "Does not work" is not a useful problem description. "My car doesn't move, what's wrong with it?"

Comment: `B member2{"needs a string"};`, NSDMI requires a brace-or-equal initializer

Comment: @SamVarshavchik fixed by telling which errors I get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it follows an example of your code once fixed:

```
#include <string>

class B {
public:
    B(std::string) { }
};

class A {
public:
  A() { }
  A(const A &cpy) { }

  B* member1{new B{"needs a string"}};
  B member2{"needs a string"};
};

int main () {
    A a;
}
```

This *works*, that's the best one can do with such a question.